# How many solutions does $a^x=2016x$ for $a > 0$ have?

Tags: derivatives

How many solutions does $a^x=2016x$ for $a > 0$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$ have? Note that for $x < 0$ we have $a^x > 0$ and $2016x < 0$ so we can consider only $x \ge 0$. Let $f(x) = 2016x - a^x$. $f(x)' = 2016 - a^x\log(a)$.

- $a < 1$

$f(x)' > 0$ and $f(0) = -1$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = \infty$ so there is one solution.

- $a = 1$

$x = \frac{1}{2016}$

How about $a > 1$?

Comment: Find $b$ such that the graphs of $b^x$ and $2016x$ are tangent to each other, then consider the cases $a<b$, $a=b$, and $a>b$.

Answer (score 1):

If $a$ is big enough, then there are no solutions because $a^x>2016x$ for all $x>0$.

The limiting case is when they touch for $x=x_0$ just greater than 0. To find $x_0$ we must solve: $$a^x=2016x,a^x\ln a=2016$$ (the 2nd equation is equality of derivatives). The 2nd equation gives $a^x=\frac{2016}{\ln a}$. Substituting in the 1st equation we get $x=\frac{1}{\ln a}$. Substituting again we get $x\ln a=\ln 2016+\ln x$ or $1=\ln 2016+\ln x$ and hence $\ln x=1-\ln2016$ or $$x_0=\frac{e}{2016}$$ and hence $$a_0=e^\frac{2016}{e}\approx 1.2368\ 10^{322}$$.

For $a>a_0$ there are no solutions. For $a=a_0$ there is the single solution $x=x_0\approx 0.00135$. For $a<a_0$ there are two solutions. The graph below shows the critical case.

[image]